# ParameterType.cookies in RestSharp v107

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, restsharp

RestSharp v107 no longer has ParameterType.Cookies.

This was my previous code in RestSharp versions lesser than v107 :

```
request.AddParameter(".AspNet.Cookies", String.Empty, ParameterType.Cookie);
```

Now after migrating to RestSharp v107, ParameterType.Cookie no longer exists. What is the equivalent to this in v107 and if not, what would be the workaround?
I do not want to downgrade RestSharp.

Answer (score 1):

You can add cookies using the custom cookie container supplied with `RestClientOptions`. It's easier if you call `client.AddCookie` extension method.

Right now, we observed issues with cookies being cross-pollinated between requests that use the same client instance. Therefore, we have changed the way we handle cookies. RestSharp will use cookie headers as the primary way to send and receive cookies. But this is a breaking change, so it will only be available in v109.

Answer (score 0):

How can the cookies be used with the client on each following request?

For example:

```
    Dim client = New RestClient(options)

    Dim login_form = New RestRequest("LoginFormURL", Method.Get)
    Dim login_form_response = client.Execute(login_form)
    
    Dim login = New RestRequest("LoginFormSubmitURL", Method.Post)        
    login.AddParameter("Name", "test")
    login.AddParameter("Password", "123456")
    Dim login_response = client.Execute(login)

    Dim user_profile = New RestRequest("UserProfileURL", Method.Get)        '
    Dim userprofile_response = client.Execute(user_profile)
```

Unfortunately, I am not logged in because the cookies are not bound to the client.

I am using the latest RestSharp 109.0.1